# Cast access protected media

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I was able to implement a PoC in Javascript for casting Photos and Videos using the Chrome Sender API for publicly accessible URLs.

In the API docs and on SO I couldn't find anything on how to handle access protected media, e.g. how to add user credentials for basic auth or how to submit an JWT.

Is this possible at all? Do I need to implement a custom Receiver to achieve this?

Comment: If you're device is supported with Digital Rights Management, you need to implement a [Custom Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver).

Comment: @jess: the media itself is not protected by any DRM, accessing the media requires authentication (on HTTP Level, e.g. Basic Auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement a custom receiver. Even though your content isn't DRM protected, to customize the requests for the media files you will have to overwrite the HTTP requests with your own auth info: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/advanced#drm